# all activity reverse when press back button

Tags: android, android-intent

In my project I create several class and I am able to going from one activity to other , but the problem is when I press back menu all activity reversed I don't want that!!!  below is manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="bones.samples.android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon48x48" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name=".stage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name="LevelOne" android:screenOrientation="landscape" ></activity>

<activity android:name="dialogue" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" ></activity>
<activity android:name="FailDialogue" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" ></activity>

<activity android:name="LevelTwo" android:screenOrientation="landscape" ></activity>
<activity android:name="LevelThree" android:screenOrientation="landscape" ></activity>

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens= "true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
</manifest>
```

I want that when I am on leveltwo or dilogeue activity and press back button it directly go to stage activity but not in reverse all activities.

Comment: simply call `finish()` when you move to another activity.

Comment: How are you starting the activity? Are you calling finish?

Comment: If you don't want the backstack you should finish() the activity while passing the intent to the next activity.

Comment: override `onBackPress` on your activity and do everything want

Comment: no I cant call finish()

Comment: How to quite game from any activity using intent pressing back button?

Answer (score 1):

If you call one activity after another without calling **finish**, the activities are preserved in the back stack for further access.

If you dont want the activities to show up when the user presses back, keep calling `finish` method after calling the activity you want.

For Ex:-

```
Intent intent =new Intenet(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will close the current activity and will start the next activity. Now, when the user presses back, it will go the the activity earlier than this activity else, your application will close.

If you want to go to a specific activity, you can override the `onBackPressed` method and call a specific activity too.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
YourActivity.this.finish()
```

after calling the `intent` to next activity, for all activities you dont want to display on BackPress.

if the above is not feasible, you can define the parent activity for up navigation:

Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the  element.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

[This is what the Docs say](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this into `Manifest`...

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

as below...

```
<activity android:name="LevelOne" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:noHistory="true" ></activity>

<activity android:name="dialogue" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
          android:noHistory="true" ></activity>
<activity android:name="FailDialogue" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
          android:noHistory="true" ></activity>
```

This attribute will remove the current `Activity` from the `Activity Stack` when another Activity will start from this Activity...So, when you will press back button then it will not return to that previous Activity.

Comment: Not necessary that stop gets called everytime while moving from one activity to another.

Comment: Sorry, `onPause()` method get called...its basic...thanks for remind.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        finish();
```

or
 set flag on your manifest file

read below thread for more info

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

or

`Use fragment`. u can replace the fragment . finally u can finish the activity.